# How to select a specific div with specific class jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a circle, when I clicked on it 2 options showed up.

```
<div class="col-sm-2" style="display: block;">
    <span class="fa fa-mobile circle-icon fa-5x client" style="background-color: rgb(75, 183, 232);">
    </span>
    <div class="line" style="display: none;"></div>
    <div class="options" style="display: block;">

        <input type="text" class="search" name="">
        <i class="fa fa-plus float-right"></i>

                        <p class="option" id="Dualstack-Pvt">
            Dualstack-Pvt
            <i class="fa fa-info-circle float-right"></i>
        </p>
                        <p class="option" id="Dualstack-Pvt-2">
            Dualstack-Pvt-2
            <i class="fa fa-info-circle float-right"></i>
        </p>
                    </div>
    <div class="selected" style="display: none;"></div>
</div>
```

I want to do something when one of the option clicked.

I can't seem to select it.

This is what I have now.

```
$('.' + selector).on("click", function() {

    if (steps.indexOf(selector) != -1) {
        nextStep = steps[steps.indexOf(selector) + 1];
    }

    let self = $(this);

    $('div.options').fadeOut('fast');

    self.animate({
        backgroundColor: fadeColor
    }, 1400);
    self.next().next('.options').slideDown(1000);

    console.log(self)


    self.find('.options').find('option').one("click", function(event) {

        console.log('%c -------->> HERE <<--------', "color: green;");


    });

});
```

This is my selection

> self.find('.options').find('option').one("click", function(event) {

I thought find() will find the matching class ... No ?

Please help me understand why this is not working ...

Comment: what is `selector`?

Comment: fa-mobile is my selector variable. Sorry.

Comment: `self.find()` looks searches the children of the element. Since you selected a `span` tag with no child elements the selector will not work. You might be looking for `.siblings('.options')` to get the sibling element with the class `options`. Although even so there is no `<option>` elements in that class or in any HTML provided, you probably mean `.option`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek may as well make that an answer. He may also consider `.nextAll()` or `.next().next()`.

Comment: @kyo Like solution you can try get to `parent()` node, like this `self.parent('div').find('option').one("click", function(event) {`

Comment: @kyo Also, you already accessed the needed level by making this `self.next().next('.options')` just extend this line to get desired result `self.next().next('.options').find('.option').one('click', function(event) {...});`

Answer (score 0):

In the query you have here:

```
self.find('.options').find('option')
```

The section `self.find('.options')` will look for elements that are the class `option` that are the children of `self`. In this case since `self` is a `<span>` with no children so the selector will not work. Note you are already doing this when you used `self.next().next('.options')`. Next the `.find('option')` part will look for the tag `<option>` and not the class `option`, so change this to `.option`. With those fixes you will have:

```
self.siblings('.options').find('.option').one("click", function(event) {

    console.log('%c -------->> HERE <<--------', "color: green;");

});
```

**Snippet example**

```js
$('.fa-mobile').on("click", function() {

    let self = $(this);

    $('div.options').fadeOut('fast');
  self.next().next('.options').slideDown(1000);

    self.siblings('.options').find('.option').one("click", function(event) {

        console.log('%c -------->> HERE <<--------', "color: green;");
        
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-2" style="display: block;">
    <span class="fa fa-mobile circle-icon fa-5x client" style="background-color: rgb(75, 183, 232);">Circle
    </span>
    <div class="line" style="display: none;"></div>
    <div class="options" style="display: block;">

        <input type="text" class="search" name="">
        <i class="fa fa-plus float-right"></i>

                        <p class="option" id="Dualstack-Pvt">
            Dualstack-Pvt
            <i class="fa fa-info-circle float-right"></i>
        </p>
                        <p class="option" id="Dualstack-Pvt-2">
            Dualstack-Pvt-2
            <i class="fa fa-info-circle float-right"></i>
        </p>
                    </div>
    <div class="selected" style="display: none;"></div>
</div>
```